# Rationale behind attribute normalisation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to learn AngularJS from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com). For creating custom directives the below example has been provided at [Custom Directives](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    return {
        template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
    };
});
</script>

</body>
```

Here the name of a directive is different in while creating it (w3TestDirective) and that used in HTML (w3-test-directive). 
If I use HTML element as `<w3TestDirective>` I see nothing in the output.

I see that AngularJS needs to perform attribute normalisation. However, I do not understand why AngularJS requires performing normalisation. 
Would someone help me understand the rationale behind AngularJS?

Comment: Just a hint: w3schools.com is not that good. Let's say .. its totally bad. It does work while using a later version of AngularJS wihout having a `restrict` param inside your directive. It does work for `AngularJS 1.5+`.

Comment: @lin I would agree with you. However I needed and example to copy from. I real intention here is to only understand why the rationale behind attribute normalisation.

Comment: I created 2 possible solutions for you with a working example. Once for `AngularJS 1.0` once for `AngularJS 1.5+`. I also added an explaination about the logic behind `restrict` param.

Comment: HTML is case insensitive. `<fooBar>` is same thing as `<foobar>`. So there's no reason why it would be normalized to `fooBar` directive. Btw, this is element, not attribute, but this applies to attributes, too.

Comment: We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. `ngModel`). However, since **HTML is case-insensitive**, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. `ng-model`). See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).

Comment: @georgeawg yep, I checked the official angular doco. However since HTML is case-insensitive, what is the need for normalisation we could have been fine with directly using <ngModel>

Comment: Because HTML is case-insensitive, directives `getUpTime` and `getuptime` would conflict. Normalization makes it `get-up-time` and `getuptime` which don't conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### About attribute normalisation in AngularJS

> We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase
>   normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since **HTML is
>   case-insensitive**, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case
>   forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g.
>   ng-model). See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization). –
>   [georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg)

Thanks to [georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg), I could not explain it any better.

---

While using `AngularJS 1.x` your have to configure `restrict`which is in your case `E` for `element`. `restict: 'E'` matches with your element tag `<w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
    };
});
</script>

</body>
```

---

While using `AngularJS 1.5+` `restrict` is set to `EA` by default which will match with the `element` and the `attribute`. `restrict: 'EA'` matches with `<w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>` and `<span w3-test-directive=""></span>`In that case your code works fine:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>
<span w3-test-directive=""></span>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    return {
        template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
    };
});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You nedd to add **restrict: 'E'**, for using directive as a html element. See this :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
    };
});
</script>

</body>
```